# How to run two batch files parallel in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch and I have two batch files: one batch file read data from **Users** table and another one read data from **Employee** table. How can I run both these batch files in parallel?

Is this possible to run this batch files with scheduling diff cron jobs if possible some one suggest me best way to do this.

### Application.java

```
   @SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class SpringBatchJobApplication {

    @Autowired
    JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("BatchConfig")
    private Job job1;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("BatchConfig2")
    private Job job2;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchJobApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(15);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(30);
        return taskExecutor;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor, JobRepository jobRepository) {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(taskExecutor);
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        return jobLauncher;
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/1 * * * * *")
    public void run1(){
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job1, params);
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/2 * * * * *")
    public void run2(){
        JobParameters params = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("JobID", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job2, params);
    }
}
```

### BatchFile1

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig2 {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;


    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader() {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<User>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setSql("SELECT id,name FROM user");
        reader.setRowMapper(new UserRowMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(rs.getString("name"));

            return user;
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessor processor() {
        return new UserItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<User>();
        writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("users.csv"));
        writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<User>() {
            {
                setDelimiter(",");
                setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User>() {
                    {
                        setNames(new String[] { "id", "name" });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<User, User>chunk(10).reader(reader()).processor(processor())
                .writer(writer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job exportUserJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportUserJob2").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).end().build();
    }
}
```

### Batchfile2

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfig2 {

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public DataSource dataSource;


    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader() {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<User> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<User>();
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setSql("SELECT id,name FROM employee");
        reader.setRowMapper(new UserRowMapper());
        return reader;
    }

    public class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper<User> {

        @Override
        public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            User user = new User();
            user.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
            user.setName(rs.getString("name"));

            return user;
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public UserItemProcessor processor() {
        return new UserItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<User> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<User>();
        writer.setResource(new ClassPathResource("users.csv"));
        writer.setLineAggregator(new DelimitedLineAggregator<User>() {
            {
                setDelimiter(",");
                setFieldExtractor(new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<User>() {
                    {
                        setNames(new String[] { "id", "name" });
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<User, User>chunk(10).reader(reader()).processor(processor())
                .writer(writer()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job exportUserJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("exportUserJob2").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).end().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `TaskExecutor` to define your jobs manually to achieve this.

Comment: Please exaplain with code

Comment: No one have idea about this?

Comment: What wrong with your application now? How it works now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring batch run multiple jobs in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56791056/spring-batch-run-multiple-jobs-in-parallel)